# Cocoapods No such module 'Siesta'

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, siesta-swift

I've just installed Siesta (1.0-beta.4) using cocoapods, but when I try to import it with import Siesta inside a swift file I receive this error: `No such module 'Siesta'`

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Siesta', '~>1.0-beta.4'
```

I'm using xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using a wrong `.xcworkspace` file.

Cocoapods requires to use `open myapp.xcworkspace` in order to open your xcodeproject correctly (with dependencies enabled correctly).

The right `.xcworkspace` file is in the project root.